# Can't Authenticate with Builtin On Screen Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

I recently lost the ability to authenticate with onscreen keyboard, for some reason? I have 20.04 installed on a Windows Tablet so need touchscreen keyboard. It pops up but can't type passwords or search activities. It's acting like onboard! I can type in applications no problem and resort to copy/paste passwrd to authenticate! How can I give builtin keyboard password permission again? I've tried caribou/onboard to no avail. What is the default OSK even called in latest ubuntu?

Comment: It's a bug in latest 20.04 update. I reinstalled fresh and authentication via onscreen keyboard worked fine. Did update and it broke OSK once again. Typing from live disk.... Reinstalling and no more updating :/

Answer (score 0):

Update: It seems xwayland 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4 was causing the authentication issues. I was able to update Ubuntu and keep xwayland 2.2 and all is well. Wayland was grabbing OSK and preventing using it to login. Not sure how to fix other than using version 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.As a walkaround,click the backspace button("X"in"○"icon) in OSK,then I can type password.I confirmed it in Xorg.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1206470)

Answer (score 0):

I just typed the password in and click the authentication box, even though I could not see the password, and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).